# Speed and Solr Search Issues with Magento Community Edition

Tags: cache, solr

I am relatively new to Magento and have been leaning over the Community Edition.

I just have three questions and I guess people like you who have used or are using Magento Community Edition can help me in this regard.

1. Have you used Magento Community Edition with a relatively mid-sized site? If yes, how is/was your experience?
2. Have you used Full Page Caching through some external module or your own customization in Magento Community Edition? Did it speed up the site effectively? How was your experience?
3. Have you implement Solr Search in Magento Community Edition? Did you implement it through some module or yourself?

Please pardon my blunt questioning. All I am hoping to hear from you guys is that Magento Community Edition is worth delving in for. All the comparisons I read made me stop at these two functionalities which Enterprise Edition has. I hope you could tell me your experiences so that I, and whole SO community can make better decisions.

Thanks

Comment: StackExchange seeks questions and answers which are possessed of some amount of certainty. While this *is* a good and fair question, it seeks general and widely-variable opinions. You may want to search for Magento whitepapers which list performance specifications, which you can use to form your own opinion.

Answer (score 2):

My experience has been with Magento community edition mainly small-mid size. It is a very flexible platform but it also comes with it's drawbacks, the more complicated the site is the harder it becomes to manage large numbers of extensions.

I've used full page caching through setting up Varnish on server with various extensions, and also using other extensions like Zoom FPC https://github.com/ezapps/Zoom-Magento-FPC. It takes a bit longer to develop & debug with such caching but the performance boost on a Magento website is worth the extra development time in my opinion. The site will be able to handle much higher traffic than without, so helps with lowering server costs. Performance should be also be tested & optimised without FPC turned on for major bottlenecks.

Also implemented Solr search integration using Mageworx extensions and there were a couple of other extensions available to integrate with Sphinx/Solr. Not too difficult once you do it a couple of times, trickiest part is setting up Solr rather than the extension. I don't know how community built extensions compares to the EE implementation of it but you can try demos and compare.